# link composable node into standalone executable

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a composable node that I want to link into a standalone executable for easier debugging with different parameters.
The idea is that the library with the composable node is linked to an executable that behaves as if this would be a standalone node.

Using the **launch system** will involve other processes and makes debugging via gdb more difficult. Using the **component manager** for debugging a single component is quite tedious as you have to start the component manager with gdb and load the component manually.

One alternative is the `dlopen_composition` executable from the `composition` package, which dynamically loads the library with the component node, instantiates and runs it: `ros2 run composition dlopen_composition <workspace>_ws/install/<package>/lib/lib<node>.so`.
However, the `dlopen_composition` does not allow to pass configuration parameters like `--ros-args --params-file`.

I found a node template `node_main.cpp.in` at https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/foxy/rclcpp_components/src/node_main.cpp.in. It looks as if this is doing the same as the `dlopen_composition` just with a hardcoded library. Can this be used in some way to create a standalone executable from a single composable node?

I do not want to use the header to specifically link or compile the node's source code into the main executable. I strongly prefer to use the standard node factories for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391385/link-composable-node-into-standalone-executable/) by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2021-11-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that, besides [`rclcpp_components_register_nodes` which is heavily used in the node composition tutorial](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/foxy/composition/CMakeLists.txt), there is also [`rclcpp_components_register_node`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/foxy/rclcpp_components/cmake/rclcpp_components_register_node.cmake). This additionally takes a parameter `EXECUTABLE` to define the name of a standalone executable for that component.

Instead of only registering one (or more) component(s) via:

```
add_library(camera_component SHARED src/CameraNode.cpp)
rclcpp_components_register_nodes(camera_component "camera::CameraNode")
```

as suggested by the tutorial, you can instead register a component and create a standalone executable like:

```
add_library(camera_component SHARED src/CameraNode.cpp)
rclcpp_components_register_node(camera_component PLUGIN "camera::CameraNode" EXECUTABLE "camera_node")
```

The node executable `camera_node` can then be used like any other standalone executable node, e.g.: `ros2 run <package> camera_node --ros-args -p <param>:=<value>`.

---

Originally posted by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) with karma: 214 on 2021-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2